# Ввод названия файла и его поиск

Tags: c++

Столкнулся с такой проблемой, не могу найти как решить ее. Программа просит ввести название файла для его поиска на диске. Но дело в том что приходится вводить полный путь к файлу, например "C:\PRIMER.txt".

Вопрос: как дописать программу чтобы не нужно было вводить полный путь, а только "PRIMER".

```
#include <iostream> // std::cout, std::cin
#include <fstream>  // std::ifstream
#include <clocale>  // setlocale( LC_ALL, "Rus" );
#include <cstdlib>  // system( "pause" );

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");

char file_name[24];
std::cout << "Введите имя файла: "; std::cin >> file_name;

std::ifstream file;
do {
    std::cout << "\nФайл не найден.\n"
    << "Введите имя файла: ";
    std::cin >> file_name;
    file.open(file_name);
    if (file.good())
    break;
    } while (true);

char   strBuff[124][124];
int    n_strok = 0;

std::cout << "\n";
while (!file.eof()) {
                    file.getline(strBuff[n_strok], sizeof(strBuff[n_strok]));
                    std::cout << n_strok + 1 << "  " << strBuff[n_strok] << "\n";
                    ++n_strok;
                    }
std::cout << "\n";

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: И где оно должно будет его искать только по имени, да еще и без расширения?

Comment: А OpenDialog Вам почему-то не годится? Там вообще ничего, только мышью кликать.

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете сами делать со вводом, что угодно.
Я бы поступил так. 
1. Если файл идет без пути - т.е., грубо говоря, без `:`, `\` (`/`) - то ищем его в некотором расположении по умолчанию (или просто в текущем каталоге).
2. Если у файла нет расширения - добавляем какое-то расширение по умолчанию.

Например, если каталог по умолчанию - `C:\ABC`, а расширение по умолчанию `.txt`, то должно быть что-то типа

```
readme      ->   .\readme.txt
readme.     ->   .\readme.
up\readme.c ->   up\readme.c
```

Примерно как-то так...

А дописать - проверки я уже указал, а уж дописать к строке второй кусочек, думаю, и сами сможете?..

Comment: Идею понял. Но не совсем понял куда это вставлять

Comment: @ADDOBOSS После ввода имени файла пользователем. Между `std::cin >> file_name;` и `file.open(file_name);`

Comment: Ошибка 3 error C2017: недопустимая escape-последовательность Ошибка 1 error C2227: выражение слева от "->C" должно указывать на тип класса, структуры или объединения либо на универсальный тип

Comment: std::cin >> file_name;
    file_name -> file_name.txt;
    file.open(file_name);

Comment: @ADDOBOSS Издеваетесь, да? :)  file_name -> file_name.txt; - примерно так: `if (file_name.find(".") == string::npos) file_name += ".txt";` - т.е. если в имени нет точки - дописать расширение...

Comment: Я еще учусь, четыре месяца в программировании). А сразу дописать нельзя вот так : std::cin >> file_name += ".txt"; ? Ведь я уверен что точки не будет при вводе, зачем тогда проверка?

Comment: @ADDOBOSS Если точно знаете - можно.

Comment: @ADDOBOSS Стоп, все назад! Я не обратил внимания, что вы работаете не со `string`, а с `char[]`. Нет, в вашем варианте - `strcat(file_name,".txt");` - только места в `file_name` выделите на всякий случай побольше...

Comment: Ругается на strcat. Увеличил file_name до 50, с запасом.                                                                                           Ошибка 1 error C4996: 'strcat': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using strcat_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS.

Comment: @ADDOBOSS Это не ошибка, а предупреждение. Можно игнорировать, можно использовать `strcat_s`, просто указав размер 50 в вашем случае.

Comment: Отлично! Все работает! Вы гений! Вы мне очень помогли, благодарю. Фууух... Сам бы только через год разобрался :)

Answer (score 0):

Можете на выводе предложить выбор директорий, либо можете для файла `file_name` конкатенацию делать, до главного пути

```
std::cin >> file_name;
file.open("C:\" + file_name + ".txt");
```

Правда `file_name` нужно делать типом `string`.